Webix DataTable style="width:NaNpx"
I have a datatable like
id: 'variantTab', view: 'datatable', css: "my_style", headerRowHeight: 50, rowHeight: 25, scroll: "xy", select: 'row', columns: [

where my_style is
.my_style .webix_hcell { text-align:center; padding-left:0;padding-right:0; }
.my_style .webix_column{ text-align:center; }
.my_style .multiline{ padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:8px; line-height:18px !important; height:1000px; /*max header height*/}
.my_style .mapview { text-align:center; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:10px; }
.my_style .mapview .webix_hcell { text-align:center; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12px; }
.my_style .mapview .webix_cell { text-align:center; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:12px; }
.my_style .right { text-align:right; }
.my_style .left { text-align:left; }
.my_style .uc  { text-transform:uppercase; } 
.my_style .lc  { text-transform:lowercase; } 
.my_style .cap { text-transform:capitalize; } 
.my_style_compact .webix_hcell { font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding-left:0;padding-right:0 }
.my_style_compact .webix_cell  { font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding-left:0;padding-right:0 }

I am re-using this in many different datatable places, but in this table my column header is misaligned width

and the image style is coming as

where value is coming as NaN, how to resolve this?

Hi, I think that the data you provided are insufficient to make any guesses or get any answers. Here's a snippet https://snippet.webix.com/cd8fap59 Could you please add something else relevant to reproduce the issue?
